# Having no margin on the header of a webpage

Tags: html, css

[Screenshot of the website's header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9FTv.png)

Hi, I attached a screenshot of the header of a website I am creating. For some reason, I can't remove the white spaces from the top and sides of the header. I tried using `margin-top: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0;` but isn't working. Here's the section of the code where the header is located and the styling I have used for it.

```
.header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #D11B1C;
    color: white;
    font-size:2rem;
    margin-bottom:2.5rem;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding-top:2.75rem;
    padding-bottom:2.75rem;
    width: 100%;

}
<h1 class="header">HEADER</h1>
```

The `<h1>` isn't inside any `<div>` and is directly after the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

you should add the following CSS for body tag:

```
body{
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
    }
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks!